# Nested TransactionScope Rollback - Is it possible?

Tags: vb.net, transactionscope, rollback

I am trying to wrap two TransactionScopes within another TransactionScope, but when I run the program and an error is triggered in the 2nd transaction scope, the 1st transaction is not rolled back. Is it possible to rollback both, or am I better off doing something else. I had to separate them due to the TransactionScope locking rows in a table and not working right.

```
Using objTransaction As New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0))

    Using objTransaction As New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0))
    'Scope - 1
    End Using

    Using objTransaction As New Transactions.TransactionScope(Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0))
    'Scope - 2
    End Using

End Using
```

Comment: Without knowing what it is you're doing in the transaction scopes, couldn't you simply nest the second transaction in the first?  As your code currently stands, you're exiting the scope of the first transaction before you enter the second, which means the first transaction can't be rolled back as it's already committed.  Just a thought - I'm not a DBA and I haven't done a lot with transactions.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong transaction scope option. To have your inner TransactionScopes enlist in the parent scope you need to use the TransactionScopeOption.Required.

When you use TransactionScopeOption of Required it will enlist in the ambient transaction if one exists. When you use RequiredNew it won't enlist in a ambient transaction.

[A great article explaining the differences is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Y1642)